# Why am I getting "1" as the class predicted all the time?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, keras

I have [this CSV file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n3w5cwbtxfgvle/mutation-train.csv?dl=1), where I'm trying to predict the `Histology` based on the data in the other rows.

I have the code shown below to do that. However, I'm getting all the predictions as `1`. Why is that? Although the accuracy I get after training the model is `86.81%`.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Activation
import keras.models as md
import keras.layers.core as core
import keras.utils.np_utils as kutils
import keras.layers.convolutional as conv

from keras.layers import MaxPool2D

from subprocess import check_output
dataset = pd.read_csv('mutation-train.csv')

dataset = dataset[['CDS_Mutation',
                   'Primary_Tissue',
                    'Genomic',
                    'Gene_ID',
                    'Official_Symbol',
                    'Histology']]

X = dataset.iloc[:,0:5].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,5].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2= LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
labelencoder_X_4= LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 4])

X = X.astype(float)
labelencoder_y= LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)

onehotencoder0 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder0.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,0:]
onehotencoder1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,0:]
onehotencoder2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [2])
X = onehotencoder2.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,0:]
onehotencoder4 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [4])
X = onehotencoder4.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,0:]

# Splitting the dataset training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

# Feature scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Evaluating the ANN
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ["accuracy"])

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3, batch_size=1)

# Evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X,y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# Calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
prediction = pd.DataFrame(predictions,columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think your data is imbalnced.

Comment: @Sociopath Thanks for your kind reply. Can you kindly clarify your point a bit? What should I do in this case?

Comment: `model.fit` has a `class_weight` argument, perhaps try assigning a higher weight to the minor class.

Comment: @Simplicity have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As you are getting 86.81% accuracy where all the values are **1**, it seems like your data is imbalanced it means in your training dataset one of the class has overpowered the other one.
So even if your predict 1 for all the test-data, you will get higher accuracy.

Refer [Accuracy paradox](https://towardsdatascience.com/accuracy-paradox-897a69e2dd9b)

Eg. In your dataset, around 85% data samples are of class **1** and remaining of class **0**.

**How to deal with it**

There are plenty of ways to deal with it.

1. Upsampling:  Create duplicate data for class **0** so both class **1** and class **0** will be in same proportion.
2. Downsampling:  Just remove some of the samples from class **1** to get same proprtion.
3. change Performance matrix: Rather than using accuracy as performance matrix use,
   F1 score, precision or recall
4. You can assign different penalties to different classes on making a mistake. In this case you give high weightage to class which has low data.

And there more ways to deal with it.

Refer [this link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/) for more details.